# How can I call a function with user selected data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a  contacts array holding list of emails. I generate div's using `ng-repeat` when user clicks i on a particular div i  call `ng-click="foo($index)"`

```
 var contacts=[someMail];

 var userSelectedContact[];

 $scope.foo=function(row)
       {

       userSelectedContact.push(contacts[row]);

       }
```

The problem is when I add `"|filter"` in `ng-repeat` to search and select a particular contact.

Since filter creates another array after filtering: When ever user selects a contact `foo($index)` is called, and it is adding some other contact which is not selected by the user.

I can understand it since I am just using `$index` which is different from the index in original contacts array before filter.

So I have to stop using either filter (or) index to find the user selected contact. 
What should i do? Is there any other way?

How can I call a function with user selected data like `ng-click="foo(someEmail)"`?

Comment: why don't you pass the whole ng-repeat item into the scope and decide what you want to use later in controller?

Comment: <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="myFunction(item)"></div> and in controller $scope.myFunction(item) { console.log(item.name); //or whatever }

Comment: thanks for reply .i do not know we can pass like that

Comment: ok, so I will post it as an answer if it's what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the whole `ng-repeat` item it the `ng-click`function

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="myFunction(item)"></div>
```

and then in the controller

```
$scope.myFunction(item) {
    console.log(item.name);
    //or whatever you want to do with the item
}
```